# Excel Formula Sum

Tags: excel

I’m trying to make a formula in excel which will sum all the values in S which have a Yes in column K. I have written this formula but it only gives me the value 0. In between the values in S I have some cells with text and I have already tried if it would work if I delete those but still, it only gives me the value 0.

```
=SUMIF(K7:K120;"Yes";S7:S120)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot? It should be working.

Comment: Added picture, can you see it?

Comment: On which cell is the formula?

Comment: Probably you have a space before or after the "Yes".

Comment: The formula is on Cell S2

Comment: If you have a space, add it to the formula as well. Like this: `=SUMIF(K7:K120;" Yes";S7:S120)` Or remove it from the table.

Comment: Nope no space in front

Comment: @Change the `Yes` to a number. If it works, then the problem is that the "Yes" was written using another keyboard layout. Something like this: `=SUMIF(K7:K120;100;S7:S120)`

Comment: Check your numbers aren't stored as text

Comment: @Vityata Now it works thank you! But how can i change this?

Comment: @IvanFilipović - simply rewrite the "Yes" using your keyboard and without spaces.

Comment: Okey it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change *Yes* to a number. Something like this: 
`=SUMIF(K7:K120;100;S7:S120)`

If it works, then the problem is that the "Yes" was written using another keyboard layout. Or with a space before it.

To fix it, rewrite the "Yes" using your keyboard, making sure there is no space before it.